# How do I rename a DataFrame column using a lambda?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.rename(x.name + "_something"))
```

I think this should return the column with _something appended to all columns, but it just returns the same df.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: I need to act on the series column by column, not on the dataframe obejct, as I'll be applying other transformations to `x` in the lambda, not shown here.

**EDIT 2 Full Context**:

I've got a time series dataframe, and I'm trying to generate features from the data.

I've written a bunch of primitive functions like:

```
def sumn(n, s):
    return s.rolling(n).sum().rename(s.name + "_sum_" + str(n))
```

When I apply those to `Series`, it renames them well.

When I apply them to columns in a `DataFrame`, the numerical transformation goes through, but the `rename` doesn't work.

(I suppose it implies that a `DataFrame` isn't just a collection of `Series`, which means in all likelihood, I now have to explicitly rename things on the df)

Comment: You need to use a lambda?

Comment: If you're doing other transformations, then that's going to get messy in a lambda - are you definitely going to put them all into a lambda or write a function instead?

Comment: They're written in separate functions. The functions act on `Series` though, and return a renamed column `my_column_cumsum` (for example).

Comment: Do you think you could make an [edit] that is a bit more representative of your actual use case - sample input/mocked up what these functions are/how they interact and desired output... I've got a couple of ideas as to what you might want but it's just guess work as it stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this use pd.concat:

```
pd.concat([df[e].rename(df[e].name+'_Something') for e in df],1)
```

Inside the list comprehension, you can add your other logics:

```
df[e].rename(df[e].name+'_Something').apply(...)
```

If you directly use df.apply, you can't change the column name. There is no way I can think of